# Minimization ( simplification ) of a logical expression

Tags: logic

So there's this super simple expression:
$(x \land y) \lor ( x \land z ) \lor (z \land y)$ .

I've been trying for a while but I am having trouble with minimizing it . Can anyone help me out or try to give me some advice how to proceed on this ? Can it even be done?

Also, it should be done without Veich or Karnaugh maps, just using basic operations with logical expressions.

Comment: To which form do you need to minimize it? It is already in disjunctive normal form. Conjunctive normal form, maybe? [Here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28x+%26%26+y%29+%7C%7C+%28x+%26%26+z%29+%7C%7C+%28y+%26%26+z%29) you can see some.

Comment: my task says that I should minimize it to it's most minimal form , disjunctive or conjunctive, whichever is smaller. Could this be a trick, that it's already minimized?

Comment: How is 'minimized' defined?  Length of statement? Number of operands? Does it need to be 'flat' (e.g CNF or DNF), or not?